# Failed step "analyzeCommits" of plugin "[Function: nx-semantic-release] when running GitHub action

Tags: github-actions, semantic-release

I have an issue with the GitHub action workflow that I have created for the purpose of automatically releasing versions of my NX monorepo. During the process, I encountered an issue when the workflow was executed, as shown below. I am using the package [nx-semantic-release](https://github.com/TheUnderScorer/nx-semantic-release) to facilitate this process of automatic versioning.

I would appreciate it if anyone with experience in this area could assist me in resolving this issue.

```bash
[10:10:33 AM] [semantic-release] › ✖  Failed step "analyzeCommits" of plugin "[Function: nx-semantic-release]"
[10:10:33 AM] [semantic-release] › ✖  An error occurred while running semantic-release: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)
    at Object.purry (/home/runner/work/andika/andika/node_modules/remeda/dist/commonjs/purry.js:43:27)
    at filter (/home/runner/work/andika/andika/node_modules/remeda/dist/commonjs/filter.js:8:20)
    at getRecursiveDependencies (/home/runner/work/andika/andika/node_modules/@theunderscorer/nx-semantic-release/src/common/project.js:31:57)
    at /home/runner/work/andika/andika/node_modules/@theunderscorer/nx-semantic-release/src/common/project.js:32:65
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at /home/runner/work/andika/andika/node_modules/@theunderscorer/nx-semantic-release/src/common/project.js:31:199
    at pipe (/home/runner/work/andika/andika/node_modules/remeda/dist/commonjs/pipe.js:27:19)
    at getRecursiveDependencies (/home/runner/work/andika/andika/node_modules/@theunderscorer/nx-semantic-release/src/common/project.js:31:30)
    at /home/runner/work/andika/andika/node_modules/@theunderscorer/nx-semantic-release/src/common/project.js:32:65 {
  pluginName: '[Function: nx-semantic-release]'
}

 >  NX   Maximum call stack size exceeded

   Pass --verbose to see the stacktrace.
```

Comment: The call stack is exceeded due to this recursion here at line # 52: https://github.com/TheUnderScorer/nx-semantic-release/blob/d10480222028891d3d36fa94cd4e3747f6ccbe6d/packages/nx-semantic-release/src/common/project.ts#L15-L57. You should [create an issue](https://github.com/TheUnderScorer/nx-semantic-release/issues/new/choose) on that repo.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by a circular dependency issue between libraries in the NX monorepo project. [Reference](https://github.com/TheUnderScorer/nx-semantic-release/issues/37)